# Python Merge List With Common Elements in the List

Tags: python, list, merge

I've a .csv file that I read the input from. It contains the username and some other user information.

One user may be listed more than one time, so I want to list all the elements from one user in a list.

So, for the code I have is this:

```
import csv

with open('raw_input.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rawInput = list(reader)

concat = []
for elements in rawInput[1:]:
    print(elements)
    concat.append([elements[0], elements[1] + "_" + elements[2] + "_" + elements[3]])
concat

 [['User 1', 'u1-c1_p1_1'],
 ['User 1', 'u1-c2_p2_2'],
 ['User 2', 'u2-c1_p1_3'],
 ['User 3', 'u3-c1_p2_4'],
 ['User 4', 'u4-c1_p3_1'],
 ['User 4', 'u4-c2_p4_6']]
```

It should look like this:

```
[['User 1', 'u1-c1_p1_1', 'u1-c2_p2_2'],
 ['User 2', 'u2-c1_p1_3'],
 ['User 3', 'u3-c1_p2_4'],
 ['User 4', 'u4-c1_p3_1', 'u4-c2_p4_6']]
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at merging? Hint: use `defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to a solution. What you need is a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
d = defaultdict(list)
for user, date in concat:
   d[user].append(date)

final_data = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[a], b])) for a, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['User 4', 'u4-c1_p3_1', 'u4-c2_p4_6'], ['User 3', 'u3-c1_p2_4'], ['User 2', 'u2-c1_p1_3'], ['User 1', 'u1-c1_p1_1', 'u1-c2_p2_2']]
```

Comment: @Imsa glad to help!